# Sum of determinants calculated with respect to diagonal matrix elements

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

I have a $3 \times 3$ matrix, say:

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I was wondering if there is a name for the quantity: 
$$
(ei-hf)+(ai-gc)+(ae-db),
$$
which is the sum of the three $2\times 2$ determinants calculated with respect to $a, e, i$, respectively.

Comment: Does it's value calculate anything interesting?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I don't really know. I was just trying to do an eigenvector calculation for an arbitrary 3x3 matrix and ended up with this quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the determinant of the $3 \times 3$ matrix $t I - A$ gives
$$\det(t I - A) = t^3 - (\underbrace{a + e + i}_{\operatorname{tr} A}) t^2 + (\underbrace{ae + ai - bd - cg + ei - fh}_{\sigma_2(A)}) t + (\underbrace{aei - \cdots}_{\det A}) .$$
We can see immediately that the quantity you're interested in is the linear coefficient, $$\sigma_2(A) = ae + ai - bd - cg + ei - fh,$$ and so it's a special case of a natural generalization of the trace and determinant.

We can put this another way: Diagonalizing gives that the determinant of $t I - A$ can also be expressed in the eigenvalues $\lambda_a$ of $A$ as
$$\det(t I - A) = \prod (t - \lambda_a) = t^3 - (\underbrace{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3}_{\operatorname{tr} A}) t^2 + (\underbrace{\lambda_2 \lambda_3 + \lambda_3 \lambda_1 + \lambda_1 \lambda_2}_{\sigma_2(A)}) - \underbrace{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3}_{\det A} :$$
$\sigma_2(A)$ is the second [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in the eigenvalues of $A$, just as (up to sign, and for $3 \times 3$ matrices) the trace and determinant are respectively the first and third elementary symmetric polynomials in the eigenvalues.

With this viewpoint in hand, we can also use [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) and the fact that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $\lambda_a^2$ to write this quantity as
$$\sigma_2(A) = \tfrac{1}{2}[(\operatorname {tr} A)^2 - \operatorname{tr} (A^2)] .$$

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to calculate.